# Ethereum fast sync and wallet balance?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, synchronization, etherscan, fast-sync

I'm planning to run a Ethereum server for getting wallet balances at a specific time, which type of node  should i run, fast sync will work ? or should i go for archive node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you need to use an `archive` node, that's because with this mode you have an historial of all states of values and balances of an account.

`Fast` sync doesn't have an historial, so you can't get balances or states in past blocks. Only the state for certain blocks kept in memory (128 for Geth).

To run an `archive` node to have an historial about data, you must use `--gcmode archive` to disable pruning.

If you use [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) to get the balances using [`eth_getBalance`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance), you can pass to this method the [block parameter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#the-default-block-parameter) to see the balances at a specific block.